# How to get image src using javascript and xpath?

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping

How can I get image src using javascript and xpath?
I tried document.evaluate, but still cannot get the result. I just don't understand how document.evaluate works so please if you could add explanation to the solution.

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="img1.jpg">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
    <div>
         <img src="img-src-i-need.jpg">
         <img src="img4.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code? please submit your code what you try for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `id` of the `<img>` be `"imageOne"` as follows:

```
<img src="http://foo.bar/blah.jpg" id="imageOne" />
```

Using javascript you can do the following:

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById("imageOne");
var imageElementSrc = imageElement.src;
```

`imageElementSrc` now holds the `src` of the `imageElement`.

`console.log(imageElementSrc)` would print `"http://foo.bar/blah.jpg"` to the console.

---

If you have only one `<img>` element as you have shown in your code, you could do

```
var imageElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
var imageElementSrc = imageElement.src;
```

in order to get the `src`.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there are multiple images withoud id attribute? :)

Comment: You could find the index of your image in your HTML code. 
For example, if it is the third `<img>` element in the HTML, you could use `var imageElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[2];`.
What `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` actually does is it returns an array of all of the `<img>` elements in your HTML document. You can then use the index to retrieve a specific element from the array.


It is however much easier to just give an id to the `<img>` element and proceed as I have shown.

Comment: I edited the code, could this method be used on the new code aswell, if yes how.

Comment: Since this is the 3rd `<img>` tag you see when you read the code, you should use `var imageElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[2];` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in javascript

```
<script>
     var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
     var imgSrcs = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
           imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
         }
    alert(imgSrcs);
</script>
```